# Post Comment with Friends User Tag

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

i wan't to Post a comment on a Page Post.
No Problem works finde with:

```
FB.api('/MY_ID_FROM_PAGE_POST/comments', 'POST', {message: 'test'}, function(resp){});
```

now i want to tag a user.
I try it with the notifications notation. Like:

```
 {
 message: 'test @[AVnA0866TTQbPZuYWv1vZlCEBZBEUIbFskwYZ6DEFEesHck54azfmccyw0YA5w129Q2dOey64hgXNdOLJhCZUo_3J-EHEZwS4lIzPm2egWsSZQ]'
 }
```

Couse of Api Verison 2 i did not become the real user id. I only become this string as a id for the users. Does someone has a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you used the example on taggable_friends, as shown here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-actions/v2.0#mentions

You should first receive the ids of the users you can tag using `user/taggable_friends` endpoint. Then you can use those IDs in the post you create.

Does that work?